# Viewing the contents of Heroku Postgres's memory

Tags: database, postgresql, memory, heroku

Heroku outputs postgres stats to the logs periodically. They're usually in the below format (formattted here for readability)

```
source=DATABASE
sample#current_transaction=175926
sample#db_size=282280108.0bytes
sample#tables=450
sample#active-connections=56
sample#waiting-connections=0
sample#index-cache-hit-rate=0.99992
sample#table-cache-hit-rate=0.99996
sample#load-avg-1m=0
sample#load-avg-5m=0
sample#load-avg-15m=0
sample#read-iops=0
sample#write-iops=0
sample#memory-total=4045204.0kB
sample#memory-free=126420kB
sample#memory-cached=1736708.0kB
sample#memory-postgres=1955744.0kB
```

I've noticed that my available free memory keeps dropping. In the example above, the percentage of free memory is ~3% (126420kB / 4045204.0kB)

I'm very interested in WHAT it's holding in memory that's taking up so much room. Is it the results of a query I keep executing? Is it a view? Is it indexes on my tables?

Is there any way to access this information? Since this is a hosted DB on Heroku, I don't have any shell access to the underlying system so all of this has to be done through the PSQL console somehow.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a way?

Comment: @Ninjarabbi - I did not :(

Comment: @user2490003 Heroku PG extras addon could give you a better idea . https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras